# DataTable and performance

Tags: .net, performance, datatable, dataset

I've just learned that a large part of my application performance loss comes from dealing with data inside a dataset.DataTable:

1. Setting value like dataset.DataTable[0].row[0][0] = value takes alot of time. The set operation take much more than it takes to find the cell , or compute the value.
2. dataset.DataTable[0].Columns.Contains("name") is also very slow. IndexOf has the same results, and manualy searching "Columns" is worse.

any ideas? (I can't stop using DS, It's too well rooted in the app)

most of the times I have 1 row with 500+ columns and 200 or more computed columns

```
private void AddComputedColumns()
    {
        Hashtable oldRowStatus = new Hashtable();
        int i = m_RowCountBeforeNextRetrive;

        for (i = m_RowCountBeforeNextRetrive; i < m_Data.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = m_Data.Tables[0].Rows[i];
            oldRowStatus[dr.GetHashCode()] = new object[] { dr.RowState, dr.RowError };
        }

        // add the computed columns
        if (m_BoComputedColumns.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (AOColumn col in m_BoComputedColumns)
            {
                if (col.Value == null)
                    col.Value = DBNull.Value;

                DataColumn dc;

                if (m_RowCountBeforeNextRetrive == 0)
                {
                    if (!m_Data.Tables[0].Columns.Contains(col.Name))
                    {
                        dc = m_Data.Tables[0].Columns.Add(col.Name, col.GetDataType());
                        dc.ReadOnly = false;
                        dc.ExtendedProperties.Add("IsComputed", true);
                        SetValueToComputedColumns(col, dc);
                    }
                    else
                        SetValueToComputedColumns(col, m_Data.Tables[0].Columns[col.Name]);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (m_Data.Tables[0].Columns.Contains(col.Name))
                        SetValueToComputedColumns(col, m_Data.Tables[0].Columns[col.Name]);
                }
            }
        }

        for (i = m_RowCountBeforeNextRetrive; i < m_Data.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = m_Data.Tables[0].Rows[i];
            object[] tmp = (object[])oldRowStatus[dr.GetHashCode()];
            if ((DataRowState)tmp[0] == DataRowState.Unchanged && ((string)tmp[1]).Length == 0)
                dr.AcceptChanges();
        }
    }

private void SetValueToComputedColumns(AOColumn col, DataColumn dc)
    {
        int i = m_RowCountBeforeNextRetrive;

        for(i = m_RowCountBeforeNextRetrive; i < m_Data.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            DataRow dr = m_Data.Tables[0].Rows[i];
            dr[dc] = col.Value;
            _syncedRowsList[i] = false;

        }
    }
```

Comment: how many rows and column do you have in your table?

Comment: Post your code.  Dataset's shouldn't be that slow.